# If $U$ is a subspace of $V$, there exists $W$ such that $T:V\to W$ has $ker(T)=U$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble working out a proof for this question, is it something to do with $U$ and $W$ being complementary subspaces?
I cannot find a way to prove that there will always exist a $W$ for all $U$.
Any hints would be much appreciated.

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Prove that there
>   exist a vector space $W$ and a linear map $T: V$ $\rightarrow$ $W$ such that $ker(T) = U$.
>   You may assume that $V$ has ﬁnite dimension

Comment: If you have done quotients, the canonical quotient map does this for you. $W$ would be played by $V/U$ and $T$ would be the canonical quotient map. Under $T$, $U$ gets sent to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Write down a basis for $U$ and extend it to a basis for $V$; let $W = V$, and find a function that vanishes on $U$ and doesn't do very much on the rest of $V$. Remeber that a map is determined from what it does to a basis here.

Comment: Ok so if I assume e_1,...,e_r is a basis of U and I extend it to e_1,...,e_r,e_r+1,...,e_n which is a basis on V, if W=V then T:V->W = T:V->V , could I define a function that any x in V where x=a1e_1+...+ane_n with at least one of a1,..ar not being zero, this x then just goes to the zero vector. And if a1,....ar are 0 then it goes t itself?

Comment: @Kimo Not quite; that won't have the right kernel. Try, instead, determining where $e_1, ..., e_r$ go to, and then where $e_{r + 1}, ..., e_n$ go.

Comment: Ok sorry about this, but would this be an improvement? All v in V with at least one of a1,...a_r being non zero and all of a_r+1,a_n are zero. This definition holds for any element in U. If this holds then linear map takes v in V to 0, if not it goes to itself?? Or, something along the lines of the linear map would be defined as all of e_1,...,e_r go to zero and all of e_r+1,...,e_n go to themselves forming a image with basis e_r+1,...,e_n? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Kimo The last sentence is the best idea, and will work.